# Should we use sudo for git operations?

Tags: linux, git

What is the difference between the following two command lines?

```
root@superhero:~/Workspace/# sudo git push origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.


root@superhero:~/Workspace/# git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: You need the correct private key in order to push to the remote Git repo.  Evidently your `root` user doesn't have that.

Comment: however, my ssh-gen and ssh-add operations are all executed by the root user...

Answer (score 3):

Using `sudo` causes the command to run as the root user. The Git command uses credentials and configuration stored in the current user's home directory; when you run as `sudo`, this code is going to be looking at the `root` home directory, not your home directory and thus miss this context.

In most cases, it should not be necessary to use `sudo`. There are very few cases where it is required (such as installing software globally such as with `apt-get`) and when it comes to programming, use of `sudo` is often but not always an anti-pattern (in order to ensure that source code is hermetic and reproducable, most software should be installed in the repository, not globally).

Answer (score 1):

When you are using sudo in your command. This is the root user that execute  the command. The key used to access to your git server are store in a directory (.ssh/). When you run the command in root. The directory is the '.ssh/' of root so not the good one.

Another point, with sudo, this is a user from sudo group that execute the command. So the sudo group does not have access to your.ssh